# Get input text /Javascript result using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm not able to get the value from the input text to output once I change the date.  I've tried all sorts of options different values, hard coding, etc...   I know it's probably a small thing I'm missing.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$searchquery = trim($_POST['reportrange']);
echo 'result' . $searchquery . '<br><br>';
?>
    <html>
     <head>...//Date Range Picker CDN tags</head>
       <body>
        <input type='text' id="reportrange" name="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: 
     pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 79%">
     <br><br>
      <div>
      <div id="searchresults">Search results :</div>
      <ul id="results" class="update">
      </ul>
      </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange').html(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
    }
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1,'month').endOf('month')]}}, cb);
    cb(start, end);
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        $('#results').html('');
        var searchString = $("#reportrange").val();
        var data = 'reportrange=' + searchString;
        if (searchString) {
            $.ajax({type: "POST",url: 'test.php',data: data,dataType: 'text',async: false,cache: false, success: function (result) {
                    $('#results').html(result);
                   // window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
       });
      });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `$('#reportrange').html(...`, to `$('#reportrange').val(...`

Comment: i've made the change on line 20 and still no go.  "        $('#reportrange').val(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));"

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated full code

**test.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['start_date']) && isset($_POST['end_date'])){
    echo 'start_date: '.$_POST['start_date'];
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'end_date: '.$_POST['end_date'];
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js">. 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var start_date;
var end_date;
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange').html(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
        start_date = start.format('MMM D, YYYY');
        end_date = end.format('MMM D, YYYY');
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 
    'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").change(function () {
        $('#results').html('');
        var searchString = $("#reportrange").val();
        var data = {'start_date' : start_date, 'end_date' : end_date};
        if (searchString) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#results').html(result);
                   // window.location.reload();

                }
            });
        }
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='text' id="reportrange" name="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: 
 pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 79%">
    <br><br>
    <div>
        <div id="searchresults">Search results :</div>
        <ul id="results" class="update"></ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks that still outputs to the results id... but doesn't POST the data.... also it only changes on the first attempt... if you go back and select another timeframe it doesn't change

Comment: I've posted full code in the answer, check this separately

Comment: thanks that works but i'm not able to post the value to a php variable for some reason.  looks like print_r($_POST); is outputting anything

Comment: I can see using dev tools that form data is being passed... but not able to output the POST details.

Comment: I also removed  <div>
  <div id="searchresults">Search results :</div>
  <ul id="results" class="update">
  </ul>
  </div>

Comment: Now, I've updated the code to get you separate "start_date" and "end_date".
Hope you got your answer now.

Brief explanation:
1. Declared start_date and end_date global variables.
2. Set start_date and end_date from daterangepicker callback function.
3. Passed these variables in ajax function.

Now, both the dates are accessible individually at server side.

Comment: Thanks that is awesome.. one last issue... is if you remove the exit; the correct dates are passed but the date in the datepicker reset and don't store the new select dates..

Comment: I posted new code above which I updated and it's not working... again thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is an updated code that isn't working..

  <?php 
  error_reporting(0);


  if(isset($_POST['start_date']) && isset($_POST['end_date'])){
  echo $startdate = $_POST['start_date'];
  echo '<br>';
  echo $enddate = $_POST['end_date'];

 }
 ?>
  <html>
  <head>
 <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js">. 
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js">. 
  </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
 
  var start_date;
  var end_date;
  $(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange').html(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' +  
 end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
    start_date = start.format('MMM D, YYYY');
    end_date = end.format('MMM D, YYYY');
   }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 
 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), 
      moment().subtract(1, 
     'month').endOf('month')]
    }
   }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
   });
   </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("input").change(function () {
    $('#results').html('');
    var searchString = $("#reportrange").val();
    var data = {'start_date' : start_date, 'end_date' : end_date};
    if (searchString) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'test1.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#results').html(result);
               // window.location.reload();

            }
        });
    }
    });
    });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php echo 'start'.$startdate; ?>
  <input type='text' id="reportrange" name="reportrange" style="background: 
   #fff; cursor: 
  pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 79%">
  <br><br>

  </body>
  </html>
```